# college football analysis -star players

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I'll try to be as detailed and clear as possible without being long-winded(hopefully).

I'm stuck trying to get a breakdown(count) of how many star players (2 stars, 3 stars, 4 stars, 5 stars) were on each college football team during a given year. If you aren't familiar with college football, the'Stars' rating is a measure of talent and ability with 5 being the best, ect. I have two datasets I'm working with: 1) college football recruits from 2013-2020, and football team stats from 2013-2020.

The recruits dataset is about 2900 rows with a columns 'player','stars', 'year', 'team', and a few more. This dataset lists the 'player' name multiple times but each row is unique (stat category values change each year, or the year values are different). The teams dataset is roughly 1000 rows(a bit less) with 'team', 'year', '4_5Stars'(4 star players), '2_3Star players' as the last two columns which are currently empty. All rows are unique for each year and the dataset has a one-to-many relationship with the other one.  I tried merging and concat but the results were too cumbersome so it's much simpler to work with separately than joining them unless I have to.

It would be ideal if I can just work with the teams dataset, filling in the 4-5 and 2-3 star columns from queries on the recruits dataset. I'm clueless right now on the best way to accomplish this because I'm so fatigued with trying to wrestle with how to put it all together with the correct sequence of stepscto get the results I'm looking for. Once I have everything I need I'll be running various stats methods and linear regression on the data including plots. Attached are some sc reenshots. Additional information can be provided if necessary. Any help would be appreciated!

[image: Recruits Dataset]
[image: Teams Dataset1]
[image]

The recruits dataset was a bear to deal with and is the result of previous concat or merge operations(which worked ok). I've tried initial queries on each team out of desperation, i.e

For example

alabama = df_recruits.query('Stars == "4" or Stars == "5"') and
alabama2012 = alabama.query('Team == "Alabama')

This yielded the results I needed but obviously it's tedious and the wrong way to approach it. I tried combining the two queries into one but it yielded 0 rows. Actually the stars are categories so I think the datatype is ok?

Comment: Q1) if  the recruits df has the fields  'player','stars', 'year' and 'team' and you need a count of player by star rating and team, why don't you just do it on the recruits data set?

Comment: That might work now that I think about it. All of the array lengths wouId be the same. I was so focused on using both datasets to get it to work. I'll try your pivot table example on it and get back to you, thanks

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you have two sets of data and creating empty 4 star and 5 stars with different teams with 3 years for sample 3 players. Hope this helps

```
import pandas as pd

# Step 1: Initialize counts for star players in the teams dataset
teams_data = {
    'team': ['Team A', 'Team B', 'Team C'],
    'year': [2013, 2014, 2015],
    '4_5Stars': [0, 0, 0],
    '2_3Stars': [0, 0, 0]
}
teams_df = pd.DataFrame(teams_data)

star_counts = {}
for _, row in teams_df.iterrows():
    key = (row['team'], row['year'])
    star_counts[key] = {
        '4_5Stars': 0,
        '2_3Stars': 0
    }

# Step 2: Iterate over the recruits dataset and update star player counts
recruits_data = {
    'player': ['Player 1', 'Player 2', 'Player 3'],
    'stars': [4, 5, 3],
    'year': [2013, 2013, 2014],
    'team': ['Team A', 'Team A', 'Team B']
}
recruits_df = pd.DataFrame(recruits_data)


for _, row in recruits_df.iterrows():
    key = (row['team'], row['year'])
    if row['stars'] >= 4:
        star_counts[key]['4_5Stars'] += 1
    elif row['stars'] >= 2:
        star_counts[key]['2_3Stars'] += 1

# Step 3: Update the teams dataset with star player counts
for _, row in teams_df.iterrows():
    key = (row['team'], row['year'])
    teams_df.loc[(_, '4_5Stars')] = star_counts[key]['4_5Stars']
    teams_df.loc[(_, '2_3Stars')] = star_counts[key]['2_3Stars']

print(teams_df)
```

[image: Output Image]

Comment: Thanks I'll give it a shot! I'll let you know if it works

Comment: Ok, well running into problems. I'm not sure this is going to work because the sizes of the arrays vary considerably. Your example works great when I tried it, however, I have 131 unique team names, 1300+ player names, and my year array consists of just 8 years(2013-2020). Not sure where to go from here. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend using a pivot table in pandas.  Example:

Set up the dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd

Players = pd.DataFrame({
'player': ["player 1", "player 2","player 3", "player 1", "player 2","player 3"],
'stars': [3, 2, 1, 5, 4, 3],
'year': [2010, 2011, 2010, 2011, 2020, 2011],
'team': ["Miami", "California", "Michigan", "Miami", "California", "Michigan"]})

#pivot
table1 = pd.pivot_table(Players, values='player', index=['stars'], columns=['team', 'year'], aggfunc= 'count')
print(table1)
```

Pivot Result:
[image]

Comment: Ok, well read my comment below. Are you saying that the pivot table option will work even though I've got 1300 player names, 130 football teams and 8 different years? How will this work?

Comment: are you not trying to create an aggregate table?  I ran it on a data set with over 1m records and it took 2 seconds on a normal pc.  Is your concern data volume or the presentation of the data or something else?

Comment: My array lengths aren't uniform like your example. I'll have 1300, 4, 8, and 130. Yours have 6 each. The first exahad 3 each. The last time I tried the first suggestion from @prudhviraj it didn't work I got an error message when I ran it, saying something like 'the arrays must be the same length'. I'll try it but I'm concerned it will trigger the same error message is all. Would it help to send you a code sample so you can see what I'm talking about?

Comment: Ok I wish I was able to send some screenshots of my code and the error messages here in the comments section.  I'll have to create a new post unfortunately..